# Change path of the page's template

Tags: page-template, paths

It's possible to create templates for pages with that:

`<?php /* Template Name: Contact */ ?>`

This templates are located on the theme folder, right? Is possible to change the default path where WP search for those templates? If I want to make a lot of templates, can I create a folder to put them?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place the page templates wherever you want (also in a separate folder) as long as the files are within the current or parent theme's directory.

UPDATE: Follow this link to get a more detailed information about the Template File Folders: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#File_Folders

Take also a closer look at the [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and the default TwentyTwelve Theme: their [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) are stored within the `page-templates` folder.

Answer (score 2):

[With WordPress 3.4](http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/) was a change that allowed you to place your custom page templates in a subdirectory of your choice. The subdirectory can be named anything you want, but it needs to be in your active theme's main folder.